# Why can't I define type="LiveData&lt;Int>" in Android Studio?

Tags: android

Code A can work well, I don't know why Code b can't work, could you tell me ?

**Code A**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>        
        <import type="androidx.lifecycle.LiveData" />

        <variable
            name="MyValue1"
            type="LiveData&lt;Integer>" />
    </data>
   ...
```

**Code B**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>        
        <import type="androidx.lifecycle.LiveData" />

        <variable
            name="MyValue2"
            type="LiveData&lt;Int>" />
    </data>
   ...
```

Comment: in B- it is Int, not Integer

Comment: Int is Kotlin's datatype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Int` is not part of [Expression language](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#common_features)  for data binding

Comment: Thanks! But I can't find more details from Expression language.

Comment: You should use Java classes for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

1. can not assign the Java's primitive type to LiveData
   [image]
2. class of `Int` is not available on Java but Kotlin does
3. class of `Integer` is available on Java but Kotlin doesn't
4. class of `Int` on Kotlin is not a primitive type, this is a wrapper class for `int` so we can assign `Int` type to LiveData